# How do you make a label change the displayed text on a specific action in Java?

Tags: java

I am attempting to do a really simple bit of homework here as follows:

Write a small application with a GUI that could be the basis of a larger application.

Your application should accept a credit card number entered into a text field.

When user clicks an Accept button, check whether number entered is exactly 16 digits.

If so, display the message 
"Number accepted: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" in a label and then clear the text field.

Else display the message "Number rejected."

I did some research and put this together within a few minutes, however, I can't find very much information on making a label change its set text. From what I understand, this should accomplish it, but rather, the program keeps stalling and nothing happens. Could someone point me in the right direction as to figuring out the cause?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cardNo = "";

    cardNo = input.next();

    int cardNoLng = cardNo.length();

    if(cardNoLng == 16){
        lblInstructions.setText("Credit card accepted: " + cardNo);
        txtUserInput.setText("");
    }else{       
        lblInstructions.setText("Number rejected.");
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to validate credit card?

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` is not a good start.

You want:

- A `JTextField`, placed on a some kind of container, probably a `JPanel`, which resides within some kind of top level container, like a `JFrame`
- A `JButton` for the user to click (also on the `JPanel` with the text field)
- A `JLabel` which displays the message you want (also on the `JPanel` with the button)
- A `ActionListener` to respond to the button been clicked

Start by having a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details

Of course, you could also have a look at [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)